# MySQL error after reordering ID column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need some help with a particular table in my database. I tried reordering a column (id) of integers, but now the present values of renamed id are taking the values of the former value.e.g

If: (before re-odering)

```
------------
id    Name
2     Stack
3     Over
4     Flow
------------
A link like page.php?id=3 gives a value of OVER which is correct
```

After re-numbering

```
------------
id    Name
1     Stack
2     Over
3     Flow
4     Name
5     Last
------------
```

When I use a link like page?id=3 i still get OVER, which is not correct. Also the new id = 5 does not return any value.

Please where could the problem be ?

**Update**

When I tried from phpMyAdmin `"SELECT * FROM tap_bios WHERE tap_bios_id = 3` I get Over instead of Flow.

Comment: what are the queries you executed?

Comment: Not in what you've shown so far I think...  can you show the code in page.php, and especially the part where the relevant query or queries are executed?

Comment: @fvu `$id = "1";
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) 
            {
                $id = intval($_GET['id']);  }
                
                else $id = 1;  
                $bios = mysql_query( "SELECT *
                FROM 
                    `tap_bios`
                WHERE 
                     `tap_bios_id` =  '{$id}'") or die(mysql_error());
                      
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($bios);`

Comment: @dotunn: don't post large blobs of code in comments. it's totally unreadble. put it into the question as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...are you sure you don't have that request cached in your browser? Try clearing the cache and rerunning the query. Also, try logging the queries and copy/pasting them into a query browser. If you get the same unexpected results when dealing directly with the database while using the queries you think are correct, it's a database issue that will require further investigation. Otherwise, you may have a caching issue happening somewhere else in the system.

Comment: When I tried the select code inside phpMyAdmin I get the abnormal result

Comment: If that's the case, when you reordered, did you actually commit your changes to the database and close the transaction? Otherwise, you might be seeing those changes in whatever tool you made the changes in, but the database is unchanged outside of it because the transaction has not been closed. If phpMyAdmin is showing you the original results, it would seem that your table does not contain the information you think it should.

Comment: It depends on the tool you used to perform the reordering. If your session in that tool is still open, try 'commit' or simply ending the session -- this will likely cause the tool to commit whatever sort of behind the scenes transactions it may be using. If the tool is not still open, I would be doubtful that the transaction is still open, in which case, your table has likely not been reordered at all. What query did you use to reorder, and how did you confirm the data was changed as expected?

Comment: Manually through what tool and with what query/queries? I'd suspect the reordering did not take effect.

Comment: Did you verify afterwards through phpMyAdmin that your changes took effect? I'm going to dinner now, but if you don't have a solution by the time I get back, we can move this discussion to chat and see if we can resolve what's going on. Some things to try in the meantime: perform the reordering again in phpMyAdmin, make sure you commit the changes, then verify through phpMyAdmin the changes have actually been committed to the database. After successful verification, your php script should work. If verification is unsuccessful, try using a different tool to reorder.

Comment: How do i actually commit changes?

Comment: See my previous comment (comment # 5)